# Is there a quick way to refactor a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  |    A     |   B
--+----------+-------
1 | Country  | Name 
2 | England  | Steven 
3 | England  | Seán 
4 | France   | Michael 
5 | Scotland | Claire 
6 | Scotland | Orla
```

Is there a quick way to reformat it so it looks like this:

```
  |    A     |    B     |   C   |   D
--+----------+----------+-------+-------
1 | Country  | Name1    | Name2 | Name3
2 | England  | Steven   | Seán  |
3 | France   | Michael  |       |
4 | Scotland | Claire   | Orla  |
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What you are looking for is called Pivot Table, take a look: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Hi! I've tried using a pivot table already but to no avail

Comment: @Dude: pivot tables can't summarise text in Excel!

Comment: I want to have them in two different cells

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in comment, what you are looking for is called Pivot Table, take a look:

[image]

Comment: It's not quite what I was looking for. It's close, but just not quite there. I would prefer the information to appear horizontally instead of vertically to conserve space

Comment: Well, that is what you can get very easy (quick way) :)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try following approach? Not super flexible but it returns what you need.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

First of I assume your data is at **A1:B5**.

1. Add a helper column which adds a unique number to country names to create unique numbers. Write the formula at **C1** and copy to **C5**

   ```
   =A1&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
   ```
2. Write your unique list of country names to **A8:A10** range
3. Type 1,2,3,... number different names in a country in to **B7:D7** range
4. In **B8** write and copy the formula along the **B8:D10** range:

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH($A8&B$7,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"")
   ```

This article explains the logic: [How to get nth match with VLOOKUP](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-get-nth-match-with-vlookup/). I just updated it to 2D version.

**Additional Note:** If you want to make unique list of countries dynamic, you can use [this method](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/get-unique-items-from-list/).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it seems like a bit more work than what I was hoping for. I thought that this would be quite easy and that I was simply missing some simple function that would do it all for me!